# SwiftUI AppIntents iOS16: How to localize Summary?

Tags: swift, android-intent, shortcut, ios16

Im trying to localize the Summary of my new SwiftUI AppIntent on my Swift project for making new Shortcuts.

I am not able to localize the Summary.
I have created a `AppShortcuts.strings` with Localize of English and Spanish languages like in this page appears: [click here](https://sowenjub.me/writes/localizing-app-shortcuts-with-app-intents/?utm_source=swiftlee&utm_medium=swiftlee_weekly&utm_campaign=issue_132).

AppShortcuts.string (es):

```
"add ${numberOne} ${numberTwo}" = "Sumar: ${numberOne} ${numberTwo}";
```

Shortcut:

```
static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("add \(\.$numberOne) \(\.$numberTwo)") {
            \.$numberThree
            \.$numberFour
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the article you have already mentioned these directives have to go into `Localizable.strings`:

> ParameterSummary –
> This one is tricky. You'd think that because it has a variable it should be with the translations of the phrases in AppShortcuts.strings, but no, it belongs in Localizable.strings.

Don't know why but that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create your translation in `Localizable.strings` this way:

```
"Do something with ${text}" = "Do something with ${text}";
```

You have to put the exact name of the parameter you are interpolating, if you do interpolate.

```
static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
    Summary("Do something \(\.$text)")
}

@Parameter(title: "To do")
var text: String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ParameterSummary strings filename like this:

```
static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
    Summary("add \(\.$numberOne) \(\.$numberTwo)", table: "AppShortcuts") {
        \.$numberThree
        \.$numberFour
    }
}
```